# 2 Admin users: 1st works fine; 2nd gets the circle with 'Please wait...' that never goes away after updating and saving Short Description/Description

Tags: product, product-description

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

We migrated our Magento 1.9.4 to 2.4.2-p1 using the Magento Migration Tool. We have 2 users:

1. Me = System Admin - no problems
2. My colleague who has limited access (specific User role)

When my colleague opens up a product, goes to CONTENT -> and updates Short Description and/or Description, when trying to 'SAVE' - **it shows the circle going around with the 'Please wait...' sign**. *This stays up on their screen and never goes away.* They can make other changes to a product and it saves fine. It's just changing in the Content tab which seems to be causing this problem.

I have created a new user (with the same User Role) but it gives the same issue. I also deleted Cache and reindexed via SSH but it did not help.

**Why is this happening and what can be done to fix this?**

Comment: There is most likely some exception or error of sorts being thrown during the ajax calls that happen whilst that circle is showing up, when it errors whatever is handling the response isn't handling the error. You should open the developer tools and have a look at the response of any failing ajax request and then update this question with the error. You may have to end up looking into your log files to get the actual error to post here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds like a Porto problem, not a you problem. If there are no helpful errors in the console or the various logs, and you don't have time or resources to go deep-diving in the code trying to hunt down the bug, then I would follow this procedure:

1. Create a test user role with all the same privileges as your admin
   user.
2. Create a test user and assign your new role to that user.
3. Start removing resources (or sections of resources) from the test role, proceeding with whichever seem most logical.
4. After each removal of resources, attempt to edit the offending fields as your test user. If successful, remove another resource (or section of resources).
5. Repeat steps 3-4 until you trigger the error.

Congratulations! You've identified the resource your colleague needs to do their job. If it's a resource you're comfortable allowing them to have, for now, add it to their role temporarily. Then file a bug report with Porto so they can issue a patch.

Of course, if your colleague doesn't need to have this power, then you can always save time and skip straight to filing the bug report. In any event, it sounds like Porto needs to patch something.